# SQL Server Case Expression not working with second condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have sql server case expression that doesn't seem to work when it gets to this line:

```
 WHEN cl.Product_Type = 'PerformanceSwap' and 
 cl.Underlying_Product_Code_IndexType IS NULL THEN
```

The full block of code is:

```
CASE
WHEN prod_map.Product_ID1 = 'CR' AND prod_map.Product_Type <> 
'PerformanceSwap' THEN  
--(mandatory for transactions where asset_class = CR)
   CASE 
     WHEN cl.AB_Payment_Frequency = 'Monthly' THEN 'MNTH'
     WHEN cl.AB_Payment_Frequency = 'Quarterly' THEN 'QURT'
     WHEN cl.AB_Payment_Frequency = 'Yearly' THEN 'YEAR'

         WHEN cl.Product_Type = 'PerformanceSwap' and 
         cl.Underlying_Product_Code_IndexType IS NULL THEN
            CASE
            WHEN cl.AB_Finance_Payment_Frequency = 'MNTH' THEN 'MNTH'
            WHEN cl.AB_Finance_Payment_Frequency = 'SW' THEN 'MIAN'
            WHEN cl.AB_Finance_Payment_Frequency = 'QTR' THEN 'QURT'
            WHEN cl.AB_Finance_Payment_Frequency = 'PA' THEN 'YEAR'
            WHEN cl.AB_Finance_Payment_Frequency = 'ZC' THEN 'YEAR'
ELSE ''
END
END
END,
```

Do I need to do another case expression within this? or something else so it can up the AB_Finance_Payment_Frequency values.

Comment: what results are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the first WHEN makes sure that prod_map.Product_Type differs from 'PerformanceSwap'. So when you reach the WHEN you say has troubles, are you sure that cl.Product_Type can hold the value 'PerformanceSwap' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you are overnesting the `case` **expressions**.

The logic for the two "outer" `WHEN` comparisons are incompatible -- just look at the `Product_Type` logic.  The second should follow the first rather than be nested.

This may be what you want:

```
(CASE WHEN prod_map.Product_ID1 = 'CR' AND prod_map.Product_Type <> 'PerformanceSwap'
      THEN  --(mandatory for transactions where asset_class = CR)
            (CASE WHEN cl.AB_Payment_Frequency = 'Monthly' THEN 'MNTH'
                  WHEN cl.AB_Payment_Frequency = 'Quarterly' THEN 'QURT'
                  WHEN cl.AB_Payment_Frequency = 'Yearly' THEN 'YEAR'
             END)
      WHEN cl.Product_Type = 'PerformanceSwap' and cl.Underlying_Product_Code_IndexType IS NULL
      THEN (CASE WHEN cl.AB_Finance_Payment_Frequency = 'MNTH' THEN 'MNTH'
                 WHEN cl.AB_Finance_Payment_Frequency = 'SW' THEN 'MIAN'
                 WHEN cl.AB_Finance_Payment_Frequency = 'QTR' THEN 'QURT'
                 WHEN cl.AB_Finance_Payment_Frequency = 'PA' THEN 'YEAR'
                 WHEN cl.AB_Finance_Payment_Frequency = 'ZC' THEN 'YEAR'
                 ELSE ''
            END)
 END)
```

However, I notice that you still have only one `ELSE` clause.  I suspect that the logic you need might be a bit different.  You should map it out and then implement it.

I would also encourage you to indent the code very carefully so you can easily follow the logic.